# Table is ready-only. Unresolved table reference in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, datagrip

Encountered this issues when trying edit data with *mac* version of **pyCharm pro 2019.3** console table

1. Tried run simple query like `select * from schema.table` but all result data return same unresolved reference error
2. No issues under **Dbeaver** with same data source

[image: Unresolved]

[image: Data source is not read only]

Any idea why isn't working before i migrate all my datasource to Dbeaver.

---

#### Update

Switch between mariaDB and mySQL driver still the same

Comment: Is this table in your database explorer?

Comment: @moscas yup, i run simple query like `select * from schema.table` but still hit this

Comment: Please show the left panel where your database is shown

Comment: @moscas fixed by re import everything to new schema, not sure why but it's work

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that finds this issue in their searches, this problem also shows up if you use column aliases in the query projection in DataGrip.

Example

```
SELECT column_a AS 'c_a', column_b, column_x FROM table;
```

That query's results in DataGrip will not support cell-contents manipulation because of the alias.  You'll receive the error "*Table is ready-only. Unresolved table reference*" when trying to make direct changes to shown content.

Remove the alias (AS 'c_a') and rerun the query to be able to make the modifications to displayed results.

Answer (score 1):

In the situation where you have multiple databases with the same structure, in your query, you will have to specify which database, in order to be able to change it from the Services tab.
For example:

- good: `SELECT * FROM development.settings ...`
- wrong:`SELECT * FROM settings ...`

Comment: This answer worked for me.